# How to prevent GCC from generating guards for static members

Tags: c++, gcc, static, g++, compiler-optimization

Following is an minimal example that sometimes generates guards and sometimes not:

```
struct A {
    inline A(int v = 0) {} // without ctors, guards are omitted
    int m1() const {
        return m;
    }
private:
    int m = 0;
};

//namespace { // without anon-ns guards are generated 
    template<typename T>
    struct X {
        static int foo() {
            // static T m; // even as local-static and -fno-threadsafe-statics, guards are generated 
            return m.m1();
        }
        inline static T m; // comment this and uncomment above to try as local-static
    };
//}

int main() {
    return X<A>::foo();    
}
```

To summarize:

- without ctor in class A, guards are never generated
- using anaon-ns prevents guards also
- making the static member `m` a static local in `foo()` still generates guards (with `-fno-threadsafe-statics`) (comment/uncomment the appropriate lines in example above)

So, how to grevent guards from being generated in the case class `A` has a ctor and using anon-ns is not possible?

Comment: You could try compiling in C++03 mode.

Comment: That is not possible because I need C++17/C++20 features.

Comment: Its a avr-g++ µC firmware. There are absolutely no needs for this guards.

Comment: @wimalopaan Are you saying that the platform doesn't support shared libraries? Without that guard a shared library upon loading is going to re-initialize that object. More importantly, multiple translation units are each going to re-initialize that `inline static` and you'd need to use the venerable schwartz counter to prevent that.

Comment: Absolutely: no OS, no shared-libs. The general solution is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key-feature to suppress guards are constinit and constexpr ctors:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
    inline constexpr A(uint8_t v) : m{v} {} // without constexpr it should not compile, but does anymay
    auto m1() const {
        return m;
    }
private:
     uint8_t m{0};
};

template<typename T>
struct X {
    static auto foo() {
        return m.m1();
    }
    constinit inline static T m{2}; // requires constexpr ctor
};
int main() {
    return X<A>::foo();    
}
```

With `constinit` the initialization must be performed on compile-time, so there is no need to generate guards. This requires a `constexpr` ctor. In the above example the ctor (at least for gcc) could be declared without `constexpr`, but this may be a pending bug.

Comment: Your solution only applies to objects initialized with `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Due to `constinit`.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the constructor of `A` as `constexpr` so that `X<A>::m` is statically initialized.

If the variable need to be dynamically initialized, then a guard has to be used to prevent multiple initialization.

Per [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#guards):

> If a function-scope static variable or a static data member with vague linkage (i.e., a static data member of a class template) is dynamically initialized, then there is an associated guard variable which is used to guarantee that construction occurs only once.

Comment: Well, but I make it a local-static and use `-fno-threadsafe-statics` with gcc, no guards should be generated. Is this a gcc bug?

Comment: If I read your above comment correctly, the `constinit` would help here?

Answer (score 1):

`inline` variables are initialized by each translation unit that includes its definition. Without that guard each translation unit would re-initialize the very same variable.

`constexpr` constructors, obviously, make the initialization *static*, so that it doesn't need run-time initialization. But objects that do use *dynamic* initialization require the guard.